# BadZipFile Erorr with list_datasets()

Tags: python

This is the error I am getting. I am a newbie in ml so I don't understand this error.

I have tried installing and uninstall emnist several times . At first the function was running fine and was downloading the dataset but then some how my internet got disconnected. And now it is showing this error.

```
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [3], line 2
      1 #Download dataset and it is 536 MB
----> 2 list_datasets()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\emnist\__init__.py:223, in list_datasets()
    221 cache_path = get_cached_data_path()
    222 results = []
--> 223 with zipfile.ZipFile(cache_path) as zf:
    224     for path in zf.namelist():
    225         match = DATASET_ZIP_PATH_REGEX.fullmatch(path)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\zipfile.py:1299, in ZipFile.__init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel, strict_timestamps, metadata_encoding)
   1297 try:
   1298     if mode == 'r':
-> 1299         self._RealGetContents()
   1300     elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1301         # set the modified flag so central directory gets written
   1302         # even if no files are added to the archive
   1303         self._didModify = True

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\zipfile.py:1366, in ZipFile._RealGetContents(self)
   1364     raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1365 if not endrec:
-> 1366     raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1367 if self.debug > 1:
   1368     print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```